# Wrong input type for account "user" in the instruction accounts object for instruction "startStuffOff". Expected PublicKey or string

Tags: rust, solana

I'm getting this error when connecting my solana program with a react app:

Wrong input type for account "user" in the instruction accounts object for instruction "startStuffOff". Expected PublicKey or string.

App.js

```
const createPostAccount = async () => {
    try {
      const provider = getProvider();
      const program = new Program(idl, programID, provider);
      console.log("ping")
      await program.rpc.startStuffOff({
        accounts: {
          baseAccount: baseAccount.publicKey,
          user: provider.wallet.publicKey,
          systemProgram: SystemProgram.programId,
        },
        signers: [baseAccount]
      });
      console.log("Created a new BaseAccount w/ address:", baseAccount.publicKey.toString())
      await getPostList();
  
    } catch(error) {
      console.log("Error creating BaseAccount account:", error)
    }
  }
```

lib.rs

```
#[program]
pub mod myepicproject {
  use super::*;
  pub fn start_stuff_off(ctx: Context<StartStuffOff>) -> ProgramResult {
    let base_account = &mut ctx.accounts.base_account;
    base_account.total_posts = 0;
    Ok(())
  }


#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct StartStuffOff<'info> {
  #[account(init, payer = user, space = 9000)]
  pub base_account: Account<'info, BaseAccount>,
  #[account(mut)]
  pub user: Signer<'info>,
  pub system_program: Program <'info, System>,
}
```

Comment: what type is your provider.wallet.publicKey on js side?

Answer (score 0):

You should convert `provider.wallet.publicKey` into String: `user: provider.wallet.publicKey.toString()`